# How get content of a dynamically appended <div> on click?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, each

I have a php file:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM table") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo "<div class=\"content-row\">
                <div class=\"row-1\">".$row['id']."</div>
                <div class=\"row-2\">".$row['name']."</div>
            </div>;
   }
}
```

In JS file:

```
success: funxction(data){ $(".content").html(data); }
```

In HTML file I have:

```
<div class="content">
    // Here the ajax put the divs
</div>
```

How can I get the content of `<div class="row-1"></div> or <div class="row-2"></div>` when I click on a button?
 The button is situated out of `.content` area. I clicked on a row, it is lighted and I click on button. When a clicked on button, I want to get the id and name div content where the row is lighted.

.............................................
Update:
I have this js code:
http://pastebin.com/bjU8Kp3L

when I click on the button, check if a row was selected; if is not selected i receive an notification, if the row is selected i want to receive div content :)

Comment: Learn [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I don't get it what you do with this button, can you set up an example ?

Comment: When I click the button, I want to get `row-1` content,  where the row is lighted/selected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamic created elements,

Bind the click-handler on a static element, and delegate the event to you dynamic ones:

```
$('.content').on('click', '.content-row > div', function(){

    $(this).text();
    //OR
    $(this).html();

});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LLk48yw6/)

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to specify : I want to take The content of the div when I click on a button that no row:  <input type="buttton" id="get-div" value="Get div content">

Comment: @Ovidiu Where is this button ? Can you please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Your example is not working because i have generated these divs with php. I have try this